# Save the result of a function in the data frame used in the function

Tags: r

I am trying to do data cleaning to lots of data frames and I created a function to do it. The problem is that I want the result of the function saved in the same `data.frame` used in the function. For example, I have this `data.frame`:

```
drdAges
```

And I created this function that transforms columns that are strings to numbers:

```
toNumeric = function (z) 
  for (i in c(2,2:ncol(z))) {
    z[,i] <- as.numeric(as.character(z[,i]))
    temp <<- data.frame(z)
  }
```

How can I have, instead of `temp`, `drdAges` as the result of the function?

Comment: `drdAges[2:ncol(drdAges)] <- lapply(drdAges[2:ncol(drdAges)], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`. This should do exactly what your function does and changes the dataframe directly. You could even put your dataframes in a list, and do a nested `lapply` to do the whole operation in one line of code: `lapply(dflist, function(x) lapply(x[2:ncol(x)], function(y) as.numeric(as.character(y))))`

Comment: Thanks! That worked fine! Thanks.